# RecursiveDirectoryIterator to only scan 1 level

Tags: php

how can I use something ilke RecursiveDirectoryIterator to only show the first level directories not sub directories.

such as

```
/folder
  |-- folder-1
  |-- folder-2
    |-- sub-folder-1
    | -- subfolder-2
```

I would like to only show the folder names of folder-1 and folder-2 (and any other folders that may be added in the future dynamically), not any files.

In the end I would like to push each result into an array like this

```
$clusters = new DirectoryIterator("/agents/");
        $cluster_array = array();

        foreach ($clusters as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo != "." && $fileinfo != ".." && $fileinfo != "conf") {
                array_push($cluster_array, $fileinfo);
            }
        }
        print_r($cluster_array);
```

edit: but the array comes out looking like this

```
Array ( [0] => DirectoryIterator Object ( [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => [glob:DirectoryIterator:private] => [subPathName:RecursiveDirectoryIterator:private] => ) )
```

but if i echo out the `$fileinfo` inside the `foreach` it show `cluster_1` which is what I want, but for some reason its not whats being pushed into the array.

Comment: to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you should use DirectoryIterator class.

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: If you don't want recursion, don't use recursion. +1